# React native Listview with fixed height not getting scrolled

Tags: listview, scroll, react-native

I have a list view with fixed height with 1000 records, Listview gets bind but it is not getting scrolled I have tried making the listview inside parent view with flex:1 also setting height of parent view, setting height of listview with flex:1 but none of them are working. please help.

Tried with

```
<ListView
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 300 }}
    enableEmptySections={true}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderListView.bind(this) }
/>

// after parent view 


<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ListView
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 300 }}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderListView.bind(this) }
    />
</View>
```

But none of them worked..please help

Answer (score 0):

My guess here but maybe try using a `<FlatList>` or try wrapping the `<Listview>`in a `<ScrollView>`. Might not work but it's worth a try. Sorry I don't have comment rights.